# Woocommerce filter returns variation attribute slug instead of value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

I'm struggling to understand a weird thing in Woocommerce Flow. Recently i've installed WPML and Woocommerce Multilingual Plugin to my eshop and since then , the attribute slug is printed on new order confirmation email and on thank you page ( products detail table ).

I've spotted the issue on line 142 of class-wc-order-item-meta.php

[File Source Code](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Order-Item-Meta.html#142)

```
return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_items_meta_get_formatted', $formatted_meta, $this );
```

Following the flow of the function i've seen that the $formatted_meta variable has the proper formatted value , but after the filter is applied an array with the slug is returned for the field value instead of the name.

Filter On :

```
[20956]=>
array(3) {
["key"]=>
string(7) "pa_size"
["label"]=>
string(14) "Μέγεθος"
["value"]=>
    string(7) "onesize"
  }
}
```

Filter Off

```
  [20956]=>
  array(3) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(7) "pa_size"
    ["label"]=>
    string(14) "Μέγεθος"
    ["value"]=>
    string(8) "ONE SIZE"
  }
```

The change doesn't seem to affect anything on the process but i'm strugling to understand why i'ts happening and i can't spot the source code where the filter performs its actions.
My site uses Wordpress 4.6 and Woocoomerce 2.6.3

Answer (score 0):

this filter is defined in `\WCML_Emails::init`, part of Woocommerce Multilingual. It returns translated meta, so if you've translated this ONE SIZE to onesize, this might be reason.